# How to add extra query parameters when using the Web Share Target API?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a PWA that I'm registering as a share target using the [Web Share Target API](https://wicg.github.io/web-share-target/), I have added the following section to my manifest file:

```
"share_target": {
  "action": "/",
  "method": "GET",
  "enctype": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "params": {
    "title": "title",
    "text": "text",
    "url": "url"
  }
}
```

I wanted to track these shares using Google Analytics, so I added the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` parameters to the action URL:

```
"action": "/?utm_source=pwa&utm_medium=share"
```

After testing it, it seems that these query parameters are being replaced with `title`, `text` and `url` as set in the `params` section and not appended to the URL, so we're loosing these initial query params.

For now as a workaround I'm checking the query string `window.location.search` if it has the sharing params and setting the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` using `gtag`:

```
gtag('set', 'campaign', {source: 'pwa', medium: 'share'});
```

But I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your manifest to

```
"action": "/pwa_share/"
```

and adding in your .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pwa_share/?(.*)$ /?utm_source=pwa&utm_medium=share&$1 [L]
```

Not 100% sure about the rewrite rule itself. Keep me posted if it works or not